# How to extrude geometry in Three.JS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to make a basic 2x8 using an extruded shape. So I made the shape, including rounded corners, but when I run it, it looks more like a napalm bomb than a board.

```
var beam = new THREE.Mesh( makeRectangle( inTOm(2), inTOm(8), inTOm(.188) ).extrude( { amount:inTOm(144) } ), stlMaterial);
```

`makeRectangle` returns a Shape with the profile to be extruded.

[image: entire extrusion]
[image: top of extrusion]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like I have to add `bevelEnabled:false` to the extrude options.